# breeze allowEmptyStrings value not copied from property type to validation context

Tags: validation, breeze

I'm customizing the auto-generated breeze metadata using [the technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101346/725866).  In addition to displayName I'm adding displayOrder and allowEmptyStrings.

This is working well, the breeze validation context automatically picks up the displayName.

Why isn't allowEmptyStrings working the same way?  The required validator seems to be built to obey the allowEmptyStrings value:

[image]